# A controller to dispatch to other controllers in Kohana without URL redirection?

Tags: controller, kohana, routes

I'm writting a CMS on the great Kohana framework where admin users can choose in the backend several kinds of pages and add them in a menu with fully customized URL.

```
Example of custom URL : "mmmm/about" or "aaa/bbb/release"
```

I have a database table where I store what should be displayed for each URL :

```
Example : 
URL : mmm/about     Pagekind : Content page ; (Page) Id : 7
URL : aaa/release   Pagekind : News         ; (News) Id : 1
```

Each page kind has its own controller (so it will be cleaner, easier to manage, easier to add new page kind) :

```
Examples :
>>> In /application/classes/Controller/Pages :
class Controller_Pages() extends Controller_Template { 
    public function action_index(){
        ...
    }
}
>>> In /application/classes/Controller/News :
class Controller_News() extends Controller_Template { 
    public function action_index(){
        ...
    }
}
```

I have a route like this that send everything to my menu controller :

```
Route::set( 'menu_path', '(<menupath>)', array('menupath' => '.*?') )
->defaults(
    array(
        'controller' => 'menu',
        'action' => 'dispatch'
    )
);
```

My menu controller should do the dispatch :

```
>>> In /application/classes/Controller/Menu :
class Controller_Menu() extends Controller_Template 
{ 
    public function action_dispatch()
    {

        // Get the path :
        $menupath = $this->request->param('menupath');

        // Get page info
        $obj = ORM::factory('tablemenu')->where('URL','=',$menupath)->find();

        // Regarding to page kind, call the appropriate controller
        switch ($obj->Pagekind)
        {
           case 'Content page' : 
              // Call controller Page with $obj->Id as page id
              // ???????? 
              // ???????? 
              break;

           case 'News' : 
              // Call controller News with $obj->Id as news id
              // ???????? 
              // ???????? 
              break;

        }

    }
}
```

So i'm stuck in the call controller part. My questions are :
  - is there a way to call a controller within a controller ? (without redirection for SEO)
  - if yes, is it clean ? reliable ?
  - is there another way to do so ? Like overwriting the Route class ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options here and I'd say both could be considered clean and reliable.

### 1. Internal Request

Kohana allows to make [internal calls](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/requests#internal-requests), so you don't have to do any redirects to achieve what you're looking for.

```
class Controller_Menu() extends Controller_Template 
{ 
    public function action_dispatch()
    {
        // Get the path :
        $menupath = $this->request->param('menupath');

        // Get page info
        $obj = ORM::factory('tablemenu')->where('URL','=',$menupath)->find();

        // Regarding to page kind, call the appropriate controller
        switch ($obj->Pagekind)
        {
            case 'Content page' : 
                $url = 'pages/action/' . $obj->Id;
                break;

            case 'News' : 
                $url = 'news/action/' . $obj->Id;
                break;
        }

        // Override current response
        $this->response = Request::factory($url)->execute();
    }
}
```

Note that this is just a quick attempt to show you how this might work (and on its own it probably won't). Note the `action` part of the url, you will want to define it at some point in order for this to work.
It's important that you actually have a route that will match the requests you're internally doing here, though.
You will also need to come up with a solution to how not to make these internal requests go via 'menu_path' Route. But since you haven't tried anything yet, I'll let you play with it and if figure it out on your own. :)

### 2. Route Filters (recommended)

*I am assuming here you are using Kohana **3.3.x** for the project, as Route filters are available only from this version.*

Instead of routing all requests to the menu controller you can handle the request within a [Route Filter](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing#route-filters).

Your route might look like this then:

```
Route::set('menu_path', '(<menupath>)',
    array(
        'menupath' => '.*?')
    )
    ->filter(function($route, $params, $request)
    {
        $menupath = $params['menupath'];

        // Get page info
        $obj = ORM::factory('tablemenu')->where('URL','=',$menupath)->find();

        if ($obj->loaded())
        {
            // Regarding to page kind, call the appropriate controller
            switch ($obj->Pagekind)
            {
                case 'Content page' : 
                    $params['controller'] = 'Page';
                    $params['id'] = $obj->Id;
                    break;

                case 'News' : 
                    $params['controller'] = 'News';
                    $params['id'] = $obj->Id;
                    break;
            }

            return $params;
        }

        return FALSE;
    })
    ->defaults(array(
        'action'    => 'index',
    ));
```

Note that there is no need to define a default controller here as you want to return 404 error if the page isn't found.
We do want to define a default action though, as I can't see it defined anywhere in your example.

You may want to consider using `Pagekind` value that matches Controller name, then you won't need a `case` for each kind and you could simply do it with:

```
if ($obj->loaded())
{
    $params['controller'] = $obj->Pagekind;
    $params['id'] = $obj->Id;

    return $params;
}
```

With this type of complexity in Route filters (more than just a few lines) I'd also recommend keeping it outside, as a separate callback function (as suggested by @Daan in the comments below), e.g.:

```
Route::set('menu_path', '(<menupath>)',
    array(
        'menupath' => '.*?')
    )
    ->filter('MyRouteHelper::myfilter')
    ->defaults(array(
        'action'    => 'index',
    ));
```

---

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use Route::get()->uri() to create the URL in the first code?

Comment: It will once a route that handles proper requests is defined. Otherwise you'll end up looping inside the `<menu_path>` Route which at the moment catches all the requests as it has no restrictions.

Comment: Nice answer, I would vote for the filter option number 2, because an extra controller just too dispatch seems bloated. Although, move complex filter logic to separated functions outside the bootstrap.php, keep your bootstrap.php clean.

Comment: @Daan I would suggest option 2 as well (as a matter of fact I will update the answer to show that). I personally keep my routes outside of `bootstrap.php` just for clarity, especially when there are many of them. And yes, it's definitely a good idea to keep the more complex filter logic outside, e.g. in a helper class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! 2nd options looks great. Don't know we can do this... 
Unluckily, I still use Kohana 3.2 but it give me a good reason to upgrade to 3.3. 
After update, i will test and validate your answer as "accepted".

Comment: Route callbacks may help (http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/routing#lambdacallback-route-logic)

Comment: Thanks Michal for your answer. I take time to try it as i need to upgrade my websites to Kohana 3.3 (I write a PHP script to do so as I have several web sites running on Kohana 3.2 https://github.com/Choufourax/upgrade-kohana-3_2-to-3_3 ).
Finaly, I tried your 2nd option and it rocks !
Just a little mistake : an extra ")" on the line : 
`->filter(function($route, $params, $request))`

Comment: Corrected the typo and... glad to be of help! :)